# Spring: Log4j doesn't write to logging file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, logging

I designed a Boot application using Spring STS.
Now, I'd like to add some logging here and there.
Then, following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm) I wrote a logforj4.properties file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, should not overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true

# Set the maximum file size before rollover
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=5KB

# Set the the backup index
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=2

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

I modified **pom.xml** with dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CarsDB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CarsDB</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.13.1.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I wrote a class to start my application, adding some code to test logger:

```
package it.CarsDB.boot;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class CarsDBApplication {

    /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CarsDBApplication.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        log.debug("Hello this is a debug message");
        log.info("Hello this is an info message");
        SpringApplication.run(CarsDBApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I put *log4j.properties* inside *src/main/java*, as shown in picture (actually I put it in *src/main/resources*, too, but it didn't help for my problem).
Now, I would expect logging to be redirected to file *{$log}/log.out*, but such file is not created and I only see logging on console.
Where am I mistaking?

Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: I expect the file is somewhere, just not where you expect it. Probably in the working directory you are running the app from. Have you tried looking for it in the whole filesystem?

Comment: I've browsed whole filesystem, looking for file log.out, but that file has not been created.

Comment: Spring uses logback, so actually you need `logback.xml` file. Check example config here: http://blog.patouchas.net/technology/logging-with-logback-and-external-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Spring Boot Documentation?

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Logging configuration needs to be in *src/main/resources* and should be named 
*log4j2-spring.xml* or *log4j2.xml*.

Log4j2 still supports the properties format, not fully sure if that works with Spring Boot as well.